# Richard Feynman Nobel Lecture, typo error?

Tags: faster-than-light, textbook-erratum

In the [*Richard P. Feynman Nobel Lecture*](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1965/feynman/lecture/), I think I saw a typo in his explanation of the retarded waves. I post it there because I did not saw anywhere on the web someone who noticed it. It is an old text, so I wonder why it was not corrected.

You don't need the full context of the text to see it, only the paragraph.

> ''I found that you get the right answer if you use half-advanced and half-retarded as the field generated by each charge. That is, one is to use the solution of Maxwell’s equation which is symmetrical in time and that the reason we got no advanced effects at a point close to the source in spite of the fact that the source was producing an advanced field is this. Suppose the source s surrounded by a spherical absorbing wall ten light seconds away, and that the test charge is one second to the right of the source. Then the source is as much as eleven seconds away from some parts of the wall and only nine seconds away from other parts. The source acting at time t=0 induces motions in the wall at time +10. Advanced effects from this can act on the test charge as early as eleven seconds earlier, or at t= -1. This is just at the time that the direct advanced waves from the source should reach the test charge, and it turns out the two effects are exactly equal and opposite and cancel out! At the later time +1 effects on the test charge from the source and from the walls are again equal, but this time are of the same sign and add to convert the half-retarded wave of the source to full retarded strength. ''

He wrote :
''Then **the source** is as much as eleven seconds away from some parts of the wall and only nine seconds away from other parts.''

I think he should have written :
  ''Then **the test charge** is as much as eleven seconds away from some parts of the wall and only nine seconds away from other parts.''

What do you think?

Comment: I wouldn't class this as a *big* typo, because it's quite clear from the context what he means. But it seems to me like you're right.

Comment: I changed the title, thank you

Answer (score 3):

I communicated with these people and they added a note to the text with the correction and my name:)

https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/info/other/Feynmans_Nobel_Lecture.pdf

They also gave me this answer :

You may also know the history of Feynman's Nobel Lecture. He have the Lecture
and then returned to Caltech. He had not prepared a written version of the talk.
The Nobel people asked for a copy, but he ignored them. Finally it was discovered
that he had given a similar lecture which had been recorded. Feynman's secretary
typed that up. She asked if Feynman wanted to review it, but he said no. So, she
sent it in. This is what has appeared in the Nobel print publication and on their website.
But, always retyped with various new errors.